# Completely remove/ uninstall Octave from my mac machine

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal, uninstall, octave

Does anyone have any idea how I can completely remove/delete/uninstall all trace of Octave from my mac machine? Preferably via Terminal in a very swift action?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Terminal: sudo port uninstall octave